# CreateItemFromTemplate with SharePoint URL Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to manipulate email templates that are housed on a SharePoint site, however, whenever I go to generate an email using the template, I receive this error:

> "Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument".

These templates are used by many people and changed frequently, so my users would not be able to store them locally.

Please find my current code below:

```
Function Gen_Email(filename As String)
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Const olFormatHTML As Long = 12345
Const olImportanceHigh As Long = 4

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'v----This causes the issue; "filename" points to a SharePoint site
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(filename)

bodyText = olMail.HTMLBody
subjectText = olMail.Subject

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

'<More code here>
End Function
```

Comment: Is the filename of `*.oft` type?

Comment: @Vityata I thought so, but looking again, they all appear to be *.msg.

Comment: Does it work, if you put the template locally?

Comment: @Vityata The template works when stored locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'CreateItemFromTemplate' function pertains to local files exclusively, which is why the above issue happened.

The solution to the above issue only requires two changes:

1. Map the SharePoint drive on your local computer ([How to Configure/Troubleshoot A Mapped Drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2616712/how-to-configure-and-to-troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives-that-connec))
2. Point the template to the mapped drive. Ensure that all users are mapping the same drive (e.g., "F:\"